# React app using webpack to be deployed on JBOSS

Tags: reactjs, jboss

Any idea how to deploy a React app or angular app to JBOSS webserver ? 
I was working on a POC project using React and webpack-dev-server and now I have a bundle.js. Is it possible to deploy the bundle.js under a JBOSS directory (webapp.war)

Or will I need somehow run my react application on a separate server and port using npm/node/express and then somehow redirect JBOSS requests to this url ?

Please help.

Comment: Is it entirely a client-side app?

Comment: yes @DavinTryon - for now entirely client side

Comment: So, you would host on JBOSS the same as hosting any static resource, right?

Comment: so I created a html page ( landing page ) under the JBOSS domain where I am referencing my bundle.js + ( react.js + reactdom.js + babel.js - through cdn's) - I can see my app's code as part of bundle.js but now I am getting this issue 'target container is not a dom element react' . Upon debugging found out its a invariant violation exception - any clue how to solve that ? I used webpack command to create this bundle.js - @DavinTryon

Comment: You bundle script tag needs to be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks Davin - I was able to solve this issue by removing some dependencies in the older app ( referencing prototype.js) and now reactApp renders correctly hosted within a view of the older app